maximum recursion depth exceeded when making an HTTP request with Eventlet and Socket.IO
Description:
I am building a Python application using Socket.IO and Eventlet to handle WebSocket communication. The server is designed to process events emitted by clients, including sending HTTP GET requests to an external API. However, I encounter the following error when attempting to make the API call:
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object


Context:

Tech Stack:

Socket.IO Server: python-socketio
Asynchronous Framework: eventlet
HTTP Requests: urllib3


Environment:

Python version: (e.g., Python 3.8.10)
Operating System: Linux


What I am trying to do:

Start a Socket.IO server with Eventlet.
Handle a WebSocket event (process_data) where I send a GET request to an external API (mock example provided below).
Process the API response and send the result back to the client.


What happens:

When the process_data event is triggered, and the API request is made, I get the maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object error.
The same API call works perfectly when tested outside the Eventlet environment.




Code Snippet:
Here’s the relevant portion of my server code:
import socketio
import eventlet
from eventlet import monkey_patch
import urllib3
import json
import logging

 Monkey patch for Eventlet
monkey_patch()

 Logging setup
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

 Initialize Socket.IO server
sio = socketio.Server(cors_allowed_origins="*")
app = socketio.WSGIApp(sio)

@sio.on('process_data')
def handle_process_data(sid, data):
    payload = data.get('payload')
    if not payload:
        sio.emit('error', {"message": "Payload is missing."}, to=sid)
        return

    logger.info(f"Payload received: {payload}")
    
     Call the external API to process the payload
    api_result = call_external_api(payload)
    if api_result:
        sio.emit('api_result', {"result": api_result}, to=sid)
    else:
        sio.emit('error', {"message": "Failed to process the data. Please try again."}, to=sid)

def call_external_api(payload):
    """ Call an external API using urllib3 """
    url = f"https://api.example.com/process?data={payload}"
    http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_NONE')   SSL disabled for testing
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer test-api-key"}

    try:
        logger.info(f"Sending request to API with payload: {payload}")
        response = http.request('GET', url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
        if response.status == 200:
            return json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8')).get("result", "Unknown Result")
        else:
            logger.error(f"API Error: {response.status} - {response.data.decode('utf-8')}")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error calling API: {e}")
        return None


What I Have Tried:

Testing the API Outside the Eventlet Environment:

The same API request using urllib3 works perfectly in a standalone script without Eventlet.


Disabling SSL Verification:

Added cert_reqs='CERT_NONE' in urllib3.PoolManager() to disable SSL verification during the API call.


Switching to Requests Library:

I initially used the requests library, but I encountered the same recursion error. I switched to urllib3 for better compatibility with Eventlet, but the issue persists.


Debugging the Call Stack:

I added logging to trace the function calls and identify potential recursive loops. The issue seems to originate from the interaction between Eventlet and the HTTP request handling.


Limiting Monkey Patching:

Modified the monkey_patch() call to exclude networking modules (e.g., monkey_patch(socket=False)), but it caused other parts of the application to fail.




What I Need Help With:

Understanding the Cause:

Why does the recursion depth error occur when making an HTTP request in the Eventlet environment?


Finding a Solution:

What is the best way to handle HTTP requests (e.g., using urllib3 or requests) in an Eventlet-based Socket.IO server?


Alternatives:

Should I switch from Eventlet to another async framework (e.g., Gevent)? If so, how would that affect compatibility with Socket.IO?




Additional Notes:

The recursion issue seems tied to the Eventlet environment, as the same HTTP request logic works outside of it.
I would prefer to keep Eventlet unless there is no viable solution.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Was this written by a chatbot?
